# Detect PropertyChanged in custom TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, propertychanged

I'm have implemented a custom `TextBox`:

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    // ...
}
```

that I'm using from XAML:

```
<MyTextBox Text="{Binding MyProperty}" />
```

and it's bound to a property in my ViewModel.

```
public class MyDataContext : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string MyProperty
    {
        get { return _myPropertyBackingField; }
        set
        {
            _myPropertyBackingField = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MyProperty"));
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

**Question:** How can I, in `MyTextBox`, detect that `MyProperty` is changed?

```
MyProperty = "NewValue";
```

Preferably, I would like to distinguish a programmatical change from when the change was triggered by the user editing the value. That is, I don't think overriding `OnPropertyChanged` works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP here.

I realised after a while that it's the binding that keeps track of updating the `TextBox` from the source (DataContext). So a possible path to take would be to call `GetBindingExpression(TextProperty)` and work something out from that.

However, I solved it by overriding `TextBoxBase.OnTextChanged`:

```
protected override void OnTextChanged(TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnTextChanged(e);
    if (!IsFocused)
    {
        // Do stuff here
    }
}
```

Since the control is not focused, the change must have been done programatically. This is not perfect since a programatical change might come when the `TextBox` has focus, but it is good enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can register to the `PropertyChanged` event of the `TextBox`'s `DataContext`.

```
var dataContext = DataContext as MyDataContext;
dataContext.PropertyChanged += dataContext_PropertyChanged;

// check for the propertyname and react
void dataContext_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "MyProperty")
    {
        // Do things
    }
}
```

So if your viewmodel raises `PropertyChanged` you textbox also gets notified. But I think that's bad practice. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: `MyTextBox` extends `TextBox` with a `Command` that is triggered `OnLostFocus` (similar to `Button`). I'd like to trigger the command also when the bound value changes programmatically.

Comment: So if the command is within your viewmodel / datacontext call ( (dataContext as MyDataContext).MyCommand.Execute(null)

Comment: That's a possible work-around. However, I use `MyTextBox` in many places and would like to avoid duplicating code.

Comment: The above code goes into MyTextBox. If your goal is to raise a command on changing text, raise the command in your setter. If you want to raise the command after a textbox event (e.g. `LostFocus`) take a look at this http://www.danharman.net/2011/08/05/binding-wpf-events-to-mvvm-viewmodel-commands/

Comment: Not sure if I understand. Executing the command in the setter would lead to duplication, wouldn't it?